# A lot of loop devices in the system

Tags: ubuntu, loop-device, squashfs

I have the following picture:

```
$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs                                            /snap/code/58
loop1  squashfs                                            /snap/core/10859
loop2  squashfs                                            /snap/core/10823
loop3  squashfs                                            /snap/flutter/50
loop4  squashfs                                            /snap/rpi-imager/150
loop5  squashfs                                            /snap/core20/875
loop6  squashfs                                            /snap/wine-platform-3-stable/10
loop7  squashfs                                            /snap/wine-platform-runtime/216
loop8  squashfs                                            /snap/wine-platform-3-stable/11
loop9  squashfs                                            /snap/audacity/756
loop10 squashfs                                            /snap/core18/1988
loop11 squashfs                                            /snap/rpi-imager/137
loop12 squashfs                                            /snap/wine-platform-runtime/212
loop13 squashfs                                            /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop14 squashfs                                            /snap/code/57
loop15 squashfs                                            /snap/sublime-text/85
loop16 squashfs                                            /snap/audacity/748
loop17 squashfs                                            /snap/sublime-text/97
loop18 squashfs                                            /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
loop19 squashfs                                            /snap/irfanview/28
loop20 squashfs                                            /snap/flutter/56
loop21 squashfs                                            /snap/core18/1944
loop22 squashfs                                            /snap/blender/111
loop23 squashfs                                            /snap/blender/65
loop24 squashfs                                            /snap/gtk-common-themes/1513
loop25 squashfs                                            /snap/core20/904
loop26 squashfs                                            /snap/irfanview/30
```

What are these mounts do here? Can I unmount them safely?

Comment: Relating, on Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/q/834093/882661

Comment: Stupid approach for maintaining packages if you ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu snaps (which is a package distribution file from Ubuntu) are mounted as loop devices, if you unmount them the related programs may stop working.

The more annoying part is when trying to see the free or used space in the filesystems, I find myself always doing:

```
df -h | grep -v snap
```

To remove those from the output

Comment: `df -x squashfs` would exclude all of these from being listed.  On a default Ubuntu system, there would not be any other `squashfs` filesystems than the Snap mounts.